At every step, add $k$ previous terms, then remove all zeros. Then $k=3$ leads to a $300,056,874$-cycle.
Recently, I've been interested with the sequence of the form:
$$a_n =\text{Zr}(\sum_{j=1}^k a_{n-j}),\ \ n≥k$$
$$a_n=1,\ \ 0≤n<k$$
Where $\text{Zr}(x)$ is just $x$ with $0$ removed in its digits (i.e. zero remover function). For $k=2$, the sequence enters a cycle that has a period of $912$.
For $k=3$, the sequence enters a very long cycle that have period of $300,056,874$ (I used the Tortoise and Hare algorithm to find this cycle. The naive algorithm would be very memory intensive), and here's the beginning of that cycle:
$$2847, 26331, 5851,... $$
Only the first 3 terms of the cycle is needed to reproduce the entire cycle. This cycle starts at $n=208,666,297$.
For $k=4$, it is unknown if it enters a cycle (feel free to try it, but i have ran the Tortoise and Hare program for $10,000,000,000$ iterations and no cycle have been found so far. ), but we expect it to cycle as the expected growth factor of the number of digits is $0.9$.
I have two questions:

Let $C_k$ be the size of the cycle that the sequence will enter, given $k$. Can anyone provide a way to calculate $C_k$ (without having to do the computationally expensive task of actually going through the sequence until it cycles) or at least come up with a good approximation for $C_k$?
Can anybody prove this sequence to cycle for all values of $k$?


Does it look like the numbers have stopped increasing? For example, by plotting regular samples or the running maximum

@BenjaminWang     Yes. The numbers seems to have stopped increasing.

What is the size of the numbers after $10^{10}$ iterations ?

@Peter Around ~10^10 (It seems that the average number of digits is between 10 and 11).

I confirm the cycle you found for $k=3$.

Not an answer but two thoughts on the heuristic about the growth of the number of digits, one supporting and one refuting.
If the numbers are very large and the digits of the sum roughly uniformly distributed among ${0, \ldots, 9}$, then if in one step all numbers have about $D$ digits then the new number will have about $\frac 9{10}(\log_{10}(k) + D)$ digits. For $D$ large this shaves off many digits and even though this does not happen with probability $1$, the potential digit increase is much lower than the potential decrease on the other end of the binomial distribution of the number of zeroes.
I tested this hypothesis in base 2: For $k=3$ the sequence is periodic (it lands on 3, 3, 7, 7, and repeats). But actually it is not periodic for $k=5$: After a handful of iterations, the number of digits is of shape $n, n, n+1, n+1, n+2$, followed by the same sequence increased by one, etc, and it should not be hard to prove that this pattern is repeating.
In fact, the sequence seems to be pre-periodic unless $k$ is of the form $2^n + 1 \geq 5$. (I checked with brute force up to $k=31$ and it ended up periodic after less than 10000 steps unless $k$ is of this form where a repeating increasing pattern appears.) So the base $2$ case could have some unexpected arithmetic and the base $3$ case is probably more representative.

The more i think of it, the more i realize it is not surprising. Every single zeroless number in base-2 are one away from a power of 2. So it doesn't make a good representation. So, yes, as you said base-3 might represent things better
